# Calculate half of the height of the last list item in an ol with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

The question is kinda simple but I can't seem to figure this thing out.

How can I calculate half of the height of the last list item in an ol with jquery?
I need this to shorten a line by this exact amount of pixels to make this thing work:

[image: my problem]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
var height_li = $('ol li:last').height()/2;
```

References

http://api.jquery.com/height/

http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/

Answer (score 0):

It can also be done in pure javascript:

```
var height = document.querySelector('ol li:last-child').offsetHeight / 2;
```